# I need help to identify a plant

Tags: identification

I have lost the label off this plant I have in a pot. 
It is a creeping plant, growing a bit like a creeping rosemary. 
I cannot recall if it has flowers. The stem is round.
It isn't a thyme the leaf shape is different.
It looks a little like summer savoury but I don't think that is it.
Can anyone help me?
[image]

Comment: You think its a herb of some kind? looks like a Hebe, or a Phlox rather than a herb. Do you recall what the flowers were like and does it have aromatic leaves?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like winter savory...

Satureja montana, is a perennial, semi-evergreen herb in the family Lamiaceae, native to warm temperate regions of southern Europe, the Mediterranean, and Africa. It has dark green leaves and summer flowers ranging from pale lavender, or pink to white. The closely related plant, summer savory is an annual plant.